# ¿Triggers en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Saludos,

tengo una tabla llamada auditoria que contiene los campos:

```
- codigo_auditoria INT 
 - fechahora_auditoria DATETIME  
 - tabla_auditoria VARCHAR  
 - operacion_auditoria VARCHAR
 - usuario_auditado VARCHAR
 - campo_actualizado VARCHAR
 - valor_antiguo VARCHAR
 - valor_nuevo VARCHAR
```

y deseo auditar diferentes tablas en esa unica y misma tabla por medio de triggers, pero no sé como hacer para que en los campos `"campo_actualizado, valor_antiguo y valor_nuevo"` la bd autodetecte que campo cambio y cual es su valor antiguo y nuevo.

NOTA: no deseo hacerlo de manera fija porque de esa manera tendria que hacer mas tablas (una por cada tabla a auditar)

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con algo así:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER "nombreX"  AFTER UPDATE ON "tabla a auditar"

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

    IF NEW."campo" <> OLD."campo" THEN
    INSERT INTO codigo_auditoria SET
        campo_actualizado = "campo",
        valor_antiguo = OLD."campo",
        valor_nuevo = NEW."campo";
    END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```